# builder.parse((new StringReader(xml)) returns DeferredDocumentImpl

Tags: java

I am trying to understand what mistake I could have made but can't find the solution.

```
public static Document getXMLFromString(String xml) {
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder;
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = (org.w3c.dom.Document) builder.parse(new InputSource(
                    new StringReader(xml)));
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doc;
    }
```

I did import org.w3c.dom.Document

I am calling this method here:

```
private Node getAuthToken(SOAPMessage responseAuth) throws SOAPException,
            TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException,
            SAXException {
        String s = indentXML(responseAuth.getSOAPPart().getContent());
        Document doc = getXMLFromString(s);
        NodeList authTokenNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("authToken");
        return authTokenNodeList.item(0);
    }
```

The NodeList is empty.

After researching on the web, everybody uses this code to parse a string to a Document. I do not have any exception but after calling the method parse(), the value of doc is set to [#document: null] DeferredDocumentImpl.

I am using everything from the org.w3c.dom.

xml is a string that contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
<context xmlns="urn:zimbra">
<session id="36" type="admin">36</session>
<change token="251"/>
</context>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<AuthResponse xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
<authToken>...</authToken>
<lifetime>...</lifetime>
<a n="zimbraIsDomainAdminAccount">false</a>
<session id="36" type="admin">36</session>
</AuthResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is how I built the string after a SOAP call:

```
String xml = indentXML(responseAuth.getSOAPPart().getContent());
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is what I am trying to do in a simple way:

```
StringBuilder soapResponse = new StringBuilder(...
...
...
);

        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder;
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = (org.w3c.dom.Document) builder.parse(new InputSource(
                    new StringReader(soapResponse.toString())));
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        NodeList authTokenNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("authToken");
        Node n = authTokenNodeList.item(0);
        String s = n.getNodeValue();
```

Comment: What is in the contents of the File, and what is the varialbe xml ?

Comment: Could you also show us the complete code of your import like Jon Skeet said in his answer

Comment: Just edited my message, thank you for your help guys, I really don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: if the XML is from a file, have you tried reading it from the file using the parse method??

Comment: The XML is the one I received after making a SOAP call. String xml = indentXML(responseAuth.getSOAPPart().getContent());

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: Looking at your updated code, I think this is the problem:

```
String s = n.getNodeValue();
```

If you look at the docs for [Node](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) you'll see that `getNodeValue()` is defined to return `null` for elements... hence the problem. My sample code uses `getTextContent()` instead, which works fine.

---

It looks like that's just going to defer expanding in-memory objects until they're required.

Have you tried calling methods on the returned document rather than just looking in the debugger? I suspect everything is actually working as intended. If not, please post a short but *complete* program which shows it misbehaving. (Note that in the sample you've given, you haven't even shown how `builder` is set, and you haven't used `factory`.)

EDIT: The code you've given works for me. Here's a quick-and-dirty - but importantly, *complete* - program (using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) to load the XML file into a string) which shows the node being found successfully:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.google.common.base.*;
import com.google.common.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = Files.toString(new File("test.xml"), Charsets.UTF_8);
        Node node = getAuthToken(xml);
        System.out.println(node.getTextContent());
    }

    private static Node getAuthToken(String xml) throws Exception {
        Document doc = getXMLFromString(xml);
        NodeList authTokenNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("authToken");
        return authTokenNodeList.item(0);
    }

    public static Document getXMLFromString(String xml) throws Exception {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
        return doc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did try to call the getElementsByTagName() method, with a tag element that I know exists.

Comment: @user393381: No, please post a short but complete program - something I can compile and run, which will show the problem.

Comment: @user393381: I've now updated my answer with a short but complete program of my own. You may want to try that...

Comment: I just posted a code thqt doesn't work for me. I still don't understand. I will try your code.

Comment: It looks like we are doing the same thing.

Comment: @user393381: You still haven't provided a *complete* program though - something I can run. Note how my code has *everything* you need to build and run it. Imports, main method etc.

Comment: @user393381: Note that you're calling `getNodeValue()` and I'm calling `getTextContent()`. They give very different results.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You were right about everything. As you suspected, it was working properly already, and I was using the getNodeValue() instead of getTextContent(). The text content is what I want, I am trying to get the difference between the two.